# Wpf show items over control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to create control wich can show items over itself (just dont clip them if there is no space)

[image]

All textblocks added to grid. Grid and control has property **ClipToBounds = false**.
Why items clipped by control in my case?

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeControl}">
                <!-- Root Grid-->
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid x:Name="TicksHolder"
                          ClipToBounds="False"
                          Background="Transparent" >
                 <!-- Items Dynamically added here-->
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And as you can see from image only right border clips items. rectangles out of right border doesnot clipped!

**I found how to reproduce with more simple code:**

```
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="112" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" Width="78" Margin="37,0,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
```

And also i noticed that Grid clips content and Canvas is not

Comment: share a XAML, it will be easier to guess having a code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think that only one way out is to use Canvas instead of grid

Comment: If you have a large complex Grid you do not need to switch out the entire Grid with a canvas.  You can just wrap whatever element you need to clip inside of a canvas, and set the canvas to the correct place with grid.row and grid.column

Answer (score 3):

ClipToBounds property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds.aspx

Comment: You need to check what is clipping the contents. Use Snoop.

Comment: http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ a tool to inspect wpf application visual tree at runtime